# Trying to create Azure B2C user with azure-graphrbac

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

We are trying to import our existing users into our B2C tenant. For this, we have been trying to use the azure-graphrbac python library.

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-user-migration) guide to register an application to be used with the graph api.

I'm using the below code to try and create a user:

```py
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac.models import UserCreateParameters, PasswordProfile

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="<CLIENT ID>",
    secret="<SECRET>",
    tenant="<TENANT ID>"
)

tenant_id = '<myb2ctenant>.onmicrosoft.com'

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)

ucp = UserCreateParameters(
    user_principal_name="my@mail.com",
    account_enabled=True,
    display_name='Martin T',
    mail_nickname='<mymail>',
    additional_properties={
        "signInNames": [{"type": "emailAddress", "value": "<mymail>"}]
    },
    user_type="LocalAccount",
    password_profile=PasswordProfile(
        password='<somepassword>',
        force_change_password_next_login=True
    )
)

user = graphrbac_client.users.create(ucp)
```

I've made sure that the client id, secret and tenant id are correct. However, I keep getting this error:

`GraphErrorException: Access Token missing or malformed.`

Does anyone have an idea as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Laurent said, you need define `resource`. The default resource is `https://management.core.windows.net/`. In your scenario, you want to create a user, the resource is `https://graph.windows.net`.

Your code also has some mistake, I modify it. The following code works for me.

```
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac.models import UserCreateParameters, PasswordProfile

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="",
    secret="",
    resource="https://graph.windows.net",
    tenant = ''   
)

tenant_id = ''

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)

ucp = UserCreateParameters(
    user_principal_name="",
    account_enabled=True,
    display_name='Martin T',
    ##I test in my lab, if I use this line, I will get error log and could not create a user.
    #additional_properties={
    #    "signInNames": [{"type": "emailAddress", "value": ""}]
    #},
    ##user_type only support Member or Guest, see this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.graphrbac.models.usercreateparameters?view=azure-python
    user_type="Member",
    mail_nickname = 'shuitest',
    password_profile=PasswordProfile(
        password='',
        force_change_password_next_login=True
    )
)

user = graphrbac_client.users.create(ucp)
```

See  SDK in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.graphrbac.models.usercreateparameters?view=azure-python).

Comment: In Laurent example, you need to create a Azure AD user for auth. In fact, grap api  also support service principal, check my answer.

Comment: In your example, it seems you want to create a local user. Python SDK does not support this. You could create a Azure AD user. See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#CreateUser  and check Python SDK.

Comment: Thanks! I was afraid that the python SDK wouldn't support local users, but I figured I would try with the additional properties. It's weird, because I *do* see the signInNames present in the User model - see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/fb4073a0e4b804290d53e1d5f90a6410a67e9c31/azure-graphrbac/azure/graphrbac/models/user.py) . Anyways, I guess Rest it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You service principal authentication needs to define "resource":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/activedirectory

```
credentials = UserPassCredentials(
        'user@domain.com',      # Your user
        'my_password',          # Your password
        resource="https://graph.windows.net"
)
```